# Accessing Twilio SMS Meta-Data?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, twilio

Trying to access the body of an [incoming text message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#instance-uri) with Twilio.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
...
module.exports = function(app) {
...
app.post('/twilio/message', jsonParser, function(request, response) {
    var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
    twiml.message('test body is ' + request.Body);
    // I also tried JSON.stringify(request.body) to see what was in body and it returned '{ñ' 
    response.type('text/xml');
    response.send(twiml.toString());
});
}
```

The following returns 'test body is undefined'. Not sure what I'm doing wrong the request data seems to be there and I can access `request.url`.

*Edit: Question updated with attempt to use body-parser library.*

Comment: You running an Express body-parser? Never mind, you're using twilio npm. It probably handles it.

Comment: I'm using express is the body-parser an additional library? I updated the question to show the includes.

Comment: Yup. https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser will fix that right up

Comment: Hey @Wainage thanks for your help here. Want to update the answer section with your suggestion and email mspeir@twilio.com for a thank you t-shirt?

Comment: I'm about to update my question with your suggestion as it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride Give me a few minutes. I'll cook up a demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm taking Twilio out of this equations (it's not the issue here). Also remember to `npm install body-parser --save`.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());


// listen for POSTs on /twilio/message
app.post('/twilio/message', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    res.end("End");
});

// start express
app.listen(8888);
```

You can test this with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) (make sure you set `x-www-form-urlencoded` as your body data (or use raw with `application/json`) to test.

I just did to make sure it works.

I've worked with Twilio in the past and this is exactly the code we used to parse the body.